# Create multiple k8s secrets ad hoc

Tags: kubernetes

With the following command: `kubectl -n ns create secret generic test2 --from-literal=username=xxxxxx` I am able to create secrets. I would like to find a way (programmatically) to use a list instead of using literal=username=xxxxxx because sometimes I need more than one literal.

What I tried is the following:

```
NS=test-ns
SF=secrets.yaml
unset SECRET_NAMES
value+=(username)
value+=(password)
echo "" > $SF
for value in "${value[@]}"
do
        kubectl -n ${NS} create secret generic test2 \
                --from-literal=$value=xxxxxx \
                -o yaml >${NS}-$secret_name.yaml
done
cat $SF
```

but it failed because it creates first the username and then it not able to create the password because the secret test2 is already exits. Do you have any idea how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addressing your comment on @whites11 answer as quoted here:

> Yes but this will not work in my case. The thing is that I have created a jenkins job and is parametrized , and I don't know each user how many literal will create.

First, you have to determine how you want your user to specify the literals in the Jenkin job parameter, for example using '=' symbol:

```
username=user1
password=p@ssword
realm=app
timezone=pdt
```

Let's say the job multi-line string parameter is passed to the job script as `$SECRETS`. Here is how you loop against the literals and construct the needed `kubectl` command:

```
ARGS=()
while read LINE
do 
    if [[ "${LINE}" != *"="* ]]; then continue; fi
    ARGS+=( "--from-literal=${LINE%%=*}=${LINE#*=}" )
done <<< "$SECRETS"
```

Now that you have the arguments to `kubectl create configmap` command in `ARGS` array variable, you can use it like below:

```
NS=test-ns
kubectl -n ${NS} create secret generic test2 "${ARGS[@]}"
```

Comment: I tried the following:                                                                                                         ARGS=(username=user1,password=password)
while read LINE
do
            if [[ "${LINE}" != *"="* ]]; then continue; fi
            ARGS+=( "--from-literal=${LINE%%=*}=${LINE#*=}" )
        done <<< "$SECRETS"

NS=test-ns
kubectl -n ${NS} create secret generic test "${ARGS[@]}"    and I got : "error: exactly one NAME is required, got 2
See 'kubectl create secret generic -h' for help and examples"

Comment: @Angel, you have to initialize `ARGS` with empty array `()`. If you want to have initial values it must be in the format of `--from-literal=key=value` just like what the while loop inserts. It should be `ARGS=( "--from-literal=username=user1" "--from-literal=password=password" )`. The `--from-literal=` is really important since that's what the `kubectl create secret` command expects.

Answer (score 4):

You can repeat the `--from-literal` flag as many times as you want:

```
$ kubectl create secret generic test2 --from-literal=username=xxxxxx --from-literal=username2=xxxxxx
secret/test2 created

$ kubectl get secrets test2 -oyaml
apiVersion: v1
type: Opaque
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: test2
data:
  username: eHh4eHh4
  username2: eHh4eHh4
```

Comment: Yes but this will not work in my case. The thing is that I have created a jenkins job and is parametrized , and I don't know each user how many literal will create.